# My team mate seems to be offended often when I review his code

Tags: java, unit-testing, coding-style

My team uses Scrum and we have code review (using Fisheye crucible), but from my observation working together for 2 years is that they care less about good code quality.

I am trying to learn code quality from reading Clean Code, and try to apply things I learn in code and by giving code review. I also had one sharing session on Clean code with my team and hoped that we all follow a good coding standard. Except me and another guy in the team, the rest are not interested in good coding practice nor the term Clean code at all.

I sense a great conflict during code review if I am the one who review my team mate's code. The is one guy that making the conflicts are so badly which I am getting tired of reviewing his code now, eventually I try to avoid a heated discussion that leads to nowhere.

Below are several examples in the my review for his code:

- Asking him to create a variable with meaningful name for a magic number that was randomly put in code.
- Asking to remove hard-coded values.
- Asking to remove duplicate codes (for a particular business logic) in almost everywhere in one class, by asking him to create a method for those duplicate code instead (this time he commented in my code review that: "I could not do it because of this and that, why don't you just do it instead of asking me?" I told him I am a reviewer and not an author of the code and as per our standard the reviewer should not modify the code as she/he likes.)
- He used static variables a lot, without any particular reasons. Even in unit tests, public static variables are declared many in the test classes. So I reviewed and put my comment asking to remove static variables instead; or if it is really needed then I suggest to have a @AfterClass method to destroy static variables when not being used (I said it's good for GC). He commented back, kind of: "Having these static variables won't cause any problems to GC for just running unit tests. Why he has to care for GC in unit tests?" and refused to change. My initial intention was that not only in unit tests, but also in production code too that we should not declare static variables as whatever we want.
- His method is generally very long, contains of different logic putting in one method. Similar to one unit test method, generally just have two unit tests: one for failed case and one for successful case. So the failure conditions are all putting in one method and the rest are for successful case being put into one method. So when I reviewed, I asked for splitting each possible business logic for testing in one smaller method, and he refused to do so a few times.

My questions are:

- I think he gets offended or I get him wrong?
- Is there any of above examples I gave wrong comments?
- Did I step on wrong line that I really offended him without me knowing?
- When you have similar situation for 2 years without getting code review process improved, what would you do?
- I tend to avoid reviewing his code and instead work on other stuffs on the board. Is that okay?

I do care for code quality as much as I can within my knowledge, it's a way to maintain a good product and also help myself to learn and improve technically. But getting into heated discussions and sometimes I feel annoyed for his comments are something I wish to avoid. But avoiding this situation for long is not a good solution I think.

Comment: Hi and welcome; I suggest you a tour into this page (https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking ): this question will be probably flagged as off topic

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and be sure to read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) This question might be better asked on a site like [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thing is: all that human interaction stuff is really complicated. Thus this community is only about pure technical things. Not sure if there is a really good place for such questions on the stackexchange network.

Comment: Having said that: do not ask *us* what we think what your coworker *might* feel. Talk to you coworker instead. And yes, I have been there: our team is pretty outspoken about clean code, but other teams are not. This is a constant struggle, and it is not a pleasant experience.

Comment: Verify that your question is on-topic on https://workplace.stackexchange.com/ -> https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic and if yes, then ask there.

Comment: On the other hand, *@AfterClass method to destroy static variables when not being used* ... ah, sorry. That simply doesn't make sense. First of all, what do you mean by "destroy", and then: this very much sounds like premature optimization.

Comment: Very entertaining geeky work drama, but it's not suitable for this site.

Comment: So, there are two dimensions in here: A) your own skill sets ... I agree with most of your points, but as said ... some of your claims are *dubious* at best B) unless you are in the position to **enforce** your vision, there isn't much you can do. If you want somebody to take action, you probably would have to start measuring effects. Like: start counting the number of bugs/defects that show up for "your clean" and "his dirty" code. But you quickly get into dangerous territory doing that.

Comment: Finally: of course, ignoring such people is OK. The real fun begins when their code starts creating issues for you, such as preventing you from writing reasonable unit tests. Like "what do you mean, not use static, why dont you just user PowerMock"?

Comment: I agree with @GhostCat. You have to building a case as to why clean code is better for the organization. Then you have to present it to your higher ups. If they don't make a big deal about it, either your case was weak or they just don't care. Either way, I wouldn't worry about it beyond that. You keep doing the right thing and maybe find a better job with like minded people.

Comment: @GhostCat: Thank you for your good advice. Yes, I had one posted on codereview, if possible could you also take a look? And I also created a question on quora for your answer (please also help me to understand your answer in destroying static variables as well): https://www.quora.com/unanswered/What-should-I-do-when-therere-always-conflicts-with-a-colleague-in-code-review-for-a-long-time-and-thats-he-is-offended-How-to-improve-code-review-process-And-is-Clean-Code-always-a-good-practice-in-code-and-in-code

Comment: Thank you @Sedrick and everybody for your good comments.